# C: How to make this function thread-safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Usually when I want to make functions thread-safe I lock the shared data, then release when I'm finished doing work.

Here I'm working with a global variable.  Simply locking and unlocking is not going to ensure that the function returns a unique value.  How do I modify the following function to be thread-safe and ensure it always returns a unique integer?

```
int count = 0;
int GetUnique()
  {
    count = count + 1;
    return count;
  }
```

Some people have mentioned making a local static variable inside the function?  How and why would this work (if true)?

Comment: The function does not need to return `count`. `int local_count; lock(); count = count + 1; local_count = count; unlock(); return local_count;`?

Comment: @iharob - The lock/unlock is overkill, the CPU has specific instructions to handle this exact use case without any locking at all.

Comment: @Geoffrey I am assuming this is required because it looks like a homework or somthing similar.

Comment: @Geoffrey: To do this in a portable way, there is no way around locking and unlocking.

Comment: @iharob: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @alk - It is very easy to make this portable with some simple defines, and this method avoids overheads of mutex locking to simply to increment a value.

Answer (score 4):

You want to in this case use an atomic increment, no need for locking or mutexes if you use GCC intrinsics. [`__sync_add_and_fetch`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) is what you are looking for here, or for VC [`InterlockedIncrement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx) will perform the same.

You could make this code portable with the following:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define SYNC_ADD_AND_FETCH(x) InterlockedIncrement(&(x))
#else
#define SYNC_ADD_AND_FETCH(x) __sync_add_and_fetch(&(x), 1)
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int v = 0;
  SYNC_ADD_AND_FETCH(v);
  printf("%d\n", v);
}
```

Making it static is not enough to protect the variable from other threads modifying it on the fly, in fact it does not help in any way.

Comment: "*not enough to*"? `static` does not help at all.

Comment: ^^^ what @alk says.  'static' in multithreaded apps'libs/whatever is usually utterly disastrous.

Comment: @Marin James - Only disasterous if atomic operations are not observed.